# I can't substitude values to a placeholder of SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to separate SQL's data with the following code:

```
$count = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets');
foreach ($count as $row) {
    $num = $row[0];
    echo 'count:'.$row[0].'<br>';
}
echo 'num value: '.$num.'<br>';
$max_page = ceil($num / 10);
echo 'page: '.$max_page.'<br>';
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
} else {
    $now = $_GET['page'];
    echo '$_GET has been set successfully<br>';
}
$disp_start = $num - 10 * ($now - 1);
echo 'disp_start value: '.$disp_start.'<br>';
$disp_end = $num - 10 * $now;
echo 'disp_end value: '.$disp_end.'<br>';
$disp = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?');
//$disp -> bindValue(':st', $disp_start);
//$disp -> bindValue(':en', $disp_end);
if ($disp->execute([$disp_end])) {
    echo 'success!';
foreach ($disp as $row) {
    echo '<div class="breakwater2">';
    echo '<div class="tweet">';
    echo '<a href="./user/'.$row['uploader'].'.php">';
    echo '<img src="', $row['avatar'], '" class="avatar1">';
    echo '<div class="cont">';
    echo '<b class="username">', $row['uploader'], '</b></a>';
    echo '<p class="contents1">', $row['contents'], '</p>';
    echo '<p class="time">', $row['time'], '</p>';
    echo '</div>';//cont
    echo '</div>';//tweet
    echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="del" value='.$row['id'].'>';
    if ($_SESSION['user']['id'] == $row['userid']) {
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete">';
    }
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<hr class="division">';
}
} else {
    echo 'failure';
    print_r ($disp -> errorInfo());
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_page; $i++) {
    if ($i == $now) {
        echo $now;
    } else {
        echo '<a href="./index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}
```

However, when I execute this code an error occurs and it says

```
failureArray ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''53'' at line 1
```

But, if I don't use a placeholder and substitute a value directly to the 'OFFSET' value, it works. How can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure your offset value is an integer, not a string.

Comment: Where is the 53 coming from ?

Comment: `Make sure your offset value is an integer, not a string.` I checked the values of $disp_start and $disp_end with var_dump(), but it says the values are integers.

Comment: `Where is the 53 coming from ?` It depends on how many datas the database has. It changes when I change $_GET['page'] value.

Comment: It's coming out as a string somehow and that's where those quotes come from, so maybe `bindValue` with the appropriate `$type` parameter set.